# Spring MVC: url passing variable page style not working

Tags: url, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc for my app. So far everything is going all. However, when I get to a page that has a variable in the url (ie, /edit/{id}), the style doesn't work on that page. In addition when I submit the form on that custom path page and try to go to another page (from the controller using the ModelAndView), the style doesn't work on that destination page which is weird cause the style works fine on that when I access it from elsewhere.

I think the reason the style is not working on the destination page is because the url still stay at the custom path with the url passing variable (localhost:8080/app/edit/5).

Comment: What do you mean, "the style"?

Comment: are you including the style sheet relatively instead of absolutely?

Comment: I meant CSS and IMG by style
Yes I am including the style relatively instead of absolutely
fyi, I used mvc:resources and it is working fine on the other pages

Comment: I solved the destination page style issue by redirecting in the Controller - return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin");

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I've just experienced this myself and am having a few issues.  As far as style sheets or JS files (basically any static resource) not being found after using a path variable, I was able to fix that by prefixing all of my style sheet or JS file links with ${pageContext.request.contextPath}.  This ensures that the server always searches for them from WebContent, rather than from the offending path variable.  I am also now having the issue of not being able to send proper requests to the other pages, but as my controllers only return Strings for the view resolver rather than ModelAndView objects, I'm not sure your solution will fit for me.